# Someone could explain me what is the meaning of に in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particle-に, english-to-japanese

皆さん、こんにちは 次のテキストはわからない文があるんですよね。 この文がわからない理由は"に"ですから。 この場合、にの意味が本当に知りませんよ！ だから、助けてください

> 『サイト内の例文の再配布は不可です。 個人での学習にお使いください』

Answer (score 3):

「XXに使う」 means "use (something) for XX".

個人での学習**に**(サイト内の例文を)使う
use (example sentences in the site) **for** personal learning

Examples:

> 料理に小麦粉を使う use flour for cooking
> 通勤に自転車を使う use a bicycle for commuting

<sub>As you may know, お使いください is 尊敬語/honorific language of 使ってください.</sub>